# Cerrar Form anterior abierto dentro de un Panel c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Les comento brevemente mi problema.

Tengo una clase para poder abrir diferentes Formularios dentro de un panel, mi problema es que cada vez que abro más Formularios los anteriores no se cierran y el programa termina Crasheando ya que se llena la memoria RAM, el codigo que use para esto es el siguiente.

```
private void AbrirFormEnPanel(object formhija)
    {
        if (this.panelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.panelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        Form fh = formhija as Form;
        fh.TopLevel = false;
        fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelContenedor.Controls.Add(fh);
        this.panelContenedor.Tag = fh;
        fh.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

He buscado un poco de información y cualquier Control de  IWin32Window. En este caso un Form, puedes hacerle un .Clear();

En tu caso sería fh.Clear();

Si tienes dudas de como usarlo puedes preguntarme.
Un placer,

Comment: Pues agradeceria mucho si pudieras darme un ejemplo de como implementarlo en mi codigo